# 2D Array consecutive elements algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, pattern-matching

I have had a task given to me which requires me to ask user for a size of 2D Array, we need to create a 2D array with the specified size, so if user opted for 8 as the size, we make an `8x8` array and we randomly fill it with either `'X'` or `'O'`.

Now the main task is to find number of `group`s in that 2D array.

4 or more 'X' which are connected (horizontally `OR` vertically `NOT` diagonally) are what makes a `group`.

For example, there are 3 groups on the following photo:

[image]

My question is if there is (there probably is) an algorithm that deals with similar problems, so please do provide reading material if you have any.

Comment: a) isn't there one more group in the south-west corner? b) isn't that to easy, to ask for an algorithm?

Comment: @userunknown No there isn't, the requirement for 'X'-es to form a group is to have 4 of those linked horizontally or vertically, there are only 3 there.

Comment: Ah, the off-by-one-error hit again. :)  Well, I overlooked the minimum size of island requierement. But if you don't have fun, working such a thing out on your own, providing at least the base of a maybe suboptimal solution - why do want to program? Show us your efforts.

Comment: @userunknown I already solved this as it was required for an exercise I was given on the course I'm attending, the problem is it was too complicated (too many loops and condition checks) and I simply **knew** that there was an algorithm of some sort for problems of this kind, hence the thread. I have some basic knowledge of algorithms, but I have yet to read a whole book on the subject, even though I have few of them on my Google Drive for when I get some free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is a particular case of the finding the number of [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) in a graph. It can be solved with a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithms.

Pseudocode of dfs version:

```
result = 0
for every non-visited cell with 'X' value
    if groupSize(cell.x, cell.y) > 3
        result += 1
return result  

groupSize(x, y)
    size = 0 
    if cell(x, y) is inside array, non-visited and has 'X' value
        mark cell(x, y) as visited  
        size = 1
        size += groupSize(x + 1, y)
        size += groupSize(x - 1, y)
        size += groupSize(x, y + 1)
        size += groupSize(x, y - 1)
    return size
```

Comment: Just read your links and it does seem to be what I was asking for.